# MongoDB Export to XSL

Tags: mongodb

How do I export the Collection from Mongo DB to xsl file.

I am using MongoVue export, but it is just displaying the Document and Number of keys in it, but not all the Key and Value pairs in the document..

Please help how  to export a mongodb collection to xsl.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of using MongoVue (I haven't used that before) but if you are ok with an extra   manual step you could always use `mongoexport` to output to a CSV file. You can then open and save as XSL via excel.

Here's the syntax for using mongoexport:

```
mongoexport -d <database> -c <collection> --csv --fields <field1,field2,...> -o <filename>
```

This will use the localhost mongo instance by defaykt so if you need to connect to another server see the docs:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/